# mapping a one-to-many where the map key is an int

Tags: mapping, persistence, openjpa

I am trying to understand the annotations MapKey and MapKeyColumn and I have found them confusing. I was reading [an article](http://hwellmann.blogspot.com.es/2010/07/jpa-20-mapping-map.html) that made me even more confused (The specification section)

I have an entity with an int field and it is not the primary key:

```
public class Connections{
...
public final int getConnectionId() { 
    return this.connectionId;
}
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "FK_StartpointTNA")
public final Endpoint getStartpoint() {
    return this.startpoint;
}
...
}
```

and in the other side I have

```
public class Endpoint{
...
 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "startpoint", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { javax.persistence.CascadeType.REMOVE })
@MapKeyColumn(name = "connectionId")
public Map<Integer, Connections> getConnections() {
    return this.connections;
}
 ....
 }
```

I dont know really how to fix this. I keep getting: org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: "connections" declared that it is mapped by "startpoint", but that is a not a field of the related type.

what is the proper way to map this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As someone posted to the [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OPENJPA-2166) you opened, get rid of the `final` on your methods.

From the JPA 2 spec:

> (Section 2.1 "The Entity Class", page 21) states: "The entity class must not be final. No methods or persistent instance variables of the entity class may be final."

Comment: well. as the jira that I opened says. I already know that, ;). damn migrations... curious that it works fine under hibernate

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and getting the same error-message
but in my case I was wrong with

`mappedBy = "foo"`

where foo must declare the field! Not the column.